# Add shebang notice to Python projects in Pyflakes linter?

Tags: sublimetext3, pyflakes

Is there a way to add a notice, similar to a PEP8 notice, if the first line in a `.py` file isn't `#!/usr/bin/env python3`?

Like how if I have a line > 80 characters, it notifies me? I'd like that same type of reminder to add the shebang to the top:

[image]

Comment: Hints like this are coming from your linter (e.g. `flake8` or `pylint`) not from Sublime; it (or rather some third party package such as [SublimeLinter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter)) is just executing that tool. As such this is more a question about whether the tool you're using to lint your code can be configured to display such a warning or not.

Comment: @OdatNurd - Ah! I think I'm using Anaconda?  How can I check what linter is in use?

Comment: I don't use that particular package, but there is documentation on it [here](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/IDE/#anaconda-linting) that seems to indicate that it uses [PyFlakes](https://pypi.org/project/pyflakes/) by default but can be configured to use [PyLint](https://www.pylint.org/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

for what it's worth, most python files *shouldn't* have a shebang -- you only want that for *executable scripts* (you don't really want most library modules to be executable for example)

the only linter that I know of that attempts to handle this sort of thing is `check-executables-have-shebangs` from [`pre-commit-hooks`](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks) -- this linter will alert you if an executable text file does not start with a shebang (it's not specific to python because the problem itself is not specific to python)

the linter itself isn't really useful outside of [`pre-commit`](https://pre-commit.com) however as it depends on the framework properly detecting "text files" and "has the executable bit set" -- there may be a sublime integration for the framework but I'm not familiar with it

disclaimer: I'm the author of `pre-commit-hooks` and `pre-commit` above (as well as one of the maintainers of `pyflakes` -- though the warning above is actually coming from [`pycodestyle`](https://github.com/pycqa/pycodestyle))